# Comparing a List<List<decimal>>

Tags: c#, list, compare, ienumerable

I had a list of type `List<decimal>`

```
List<List<decimal>> Lili = new List<List<decimal>>();
List<decimal> li1 = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> li2 = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> li3 = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> li4 = new List<decimal>();

li1.Add(1);
li1.Add(2);
li1.Add(3);

li2.Add(1);
li2.Add(2);
li2.Add(3);

li3.Add(1);
li3.Add(2);
li3.Add(3);

li4.Add(1);
li4.Add(2);
li4.Add(3);

Lili.Add(li1);
Lili.Add(li2);
Lili.Add(li3);
Lili.Add(li4);
```

i Want to make a method which compare all lists of `Lili` which return that all list are same or not

Please give me suggestions from which i'll do it easily or is there any direct way to do this problem

THANKS

Comment: Does the order of each list matter? What would you want it to return if the list of lists was empty?

Comment: order of list does not matter and no list is empty

Comment: i want to return that all lists are equal or not

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, then you should consider using sets instead... as it is, you need to consider whether { 1, 2, 3 } is equal to { 1, 2, 3, 3 }. I was asking what you want the result to be if the list of lists is empty though.

Comment: how could i use sets i didnt get it properly

Comment: Well we can't tell you whether or not sets are appropriate until you've explained your requirements more clearly.

Comment: may b i am unable to explain what i want ..BTW thanks @JonSkeet for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't care about the order of the Elements in the inner Lists you should use HashSet.

so

```
List<HashSet<decimal>> lili = new List<HashSet<decimal>>();
HashSet<decimal> li1 = new HashSet<decimal>();
…
li1.Add(1);
```

Then testing if two HashSets have the same elements is as simple as

```
first.IsSupersetOf(second) && first.IsSubsetOf(second)
```

Now we can take two HashSets check if they are the same. If so only replace both hashsets with a single copy and otherwise forget the lists (replace them with `null`). We repeat that until we only have a single item left. If it is non-null they where all the same:

```
using System.Linq;
lili.Aggregate((first, second) => (first != null && second != null && first.IsSupersetOf(second) && first.IsSubsetOf(second))
                              ? first : null) != null;
```